# Java running code from command line

Tags: java, macos, command-line, twitter4j

I'm on Mac OS X 10.9.2 (Mavericks). I have code that uses an external Java library (twitter4j). It runs fine when I run it through NetBeans. However, trying to run almost identical code in the terminal gives me errors.

My directory structure is straightforward- I have a 'src' folder with the .java file and a 'lib' folder with the external .jar files I use.

From the src folder, I call `javac -cp "../lib/*" MyProgram.java` which seems to work alright. Now, if I call `java MyProgram`, I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/StreamListener
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3040)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3010)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1776)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.StreamListener
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

It seems to have trouble properly importing the external twitter4j library. What am I missing here?

These are my import statements in the code:
`import twitter4j.*;`, `import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;`

UPDATE: Using suggestions below, I also tried running it via `java -cp "../lib/*" MyProgram` which gives: "Could not find or load main class MyProgram"

Comment: You have to also add the twitter library classpath to the `java` command, so the compiled class files can be loaded by the classloader.

Comment: You can create a fatJar that includes the library then run the jar file.

Comment: I tried that as well: `java -cp "../lib/*" MyProgram` which starts throwing a new error: Could not find or load main class MyProgram

Comment: Are you compiling the code ?

Comment: When reading a stacktrace you need to understand the innermost exception - here `NoClassDefFoundError`.  When you do you also know what you need to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the classpath when running the program as well as when compiling it:

E.g.

```
java -cp "../lib/*" MyProgram
```

Comment: Running the above gives me: Could not find or load main class MyProgram